# Equalization Two Lists in java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

i have two lists (personList From DB and inputPersonList from UI).
I want to make sure each row in personList find (matches) corresponding row in inputPersonList according to id(without sort)

```
Person person1=new Person();
Person person2=new Person();
Person person1=new Person();
List<Person> personList=new ArrayList();
List<Person> inputPersonList=new ArrayList();

person1.Id(1);
person1.setName("A");
person1.setFamily("B");

person2.Id(2);
person2.setName("C");
person2.setFamily("D");

person3.Id(3);
person3.setName("E");
person3.setFamily("F");

personList.add(person1);
personList.add(person2);
personList.add(person3);

inputPersonList.add(person1);
inputPersonList.add(person3);
inputPersonList.add(person2);
```

Comment: Can you show us any example or sample? What have you done/tried so far? Why do you hold two independent lists if their contents somehow depend on each other?

Comment: @deHaar  i want equal these list according to `person.getId`

Comment: @deHaar i want this check with two for loop

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list contains a custom Object. If so just overwrite the `compareTo` method in your custom Object and then iterate through the `List`, checking each corresponding element.

For example:

Here is a custom Book object that `implements Comparable`:

```
public class Book implements Comparable {

String isbn;
String title;

public Book(String id, String title) {
    this.isbn = id;
    this.title = title;
}

String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return Comparator
            .comparing(Book::getIsbn)
            .thenComparing(Book::getTitle)
            .compare(this, (Book) o);
}

@Override
public  String toString() {
    String output = new StringBuilder()
            .append(isbn).append(":").append(title)
            .toString();
    return output;
}

}
```

The following creates two lists (to represent the DB list and the UI lists) and then compares them based on position in the list (namely "corresponding row"):

```
 public void CompareTwoLists(){
    List<Book> libraryUI = new ArrayList<>();
    libraryUI.add(new Book("9780593098240", "Children of Dune"));
    libraryUI.add(new Book("9780593098233", "Dune Messiah"));
    libraryUI.add(new Book("9780441172719", "Dune"));

    List<Book> libraryDB = new ArrayList<>();
    libraryDB.add(new Book("9780593098240", "Children of Dune"));
    libraryDB.add(new Book("9780593098233", "Dune Messiah"));
    libraryDB.add(new Book("9788886845687", "God Emperor of Dune"));

    boolean theSame = Boolean.TRUE;
    if(libraryDB.size() != libraryUI.size()) {
        theSame = Boolean.FALSE;
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < libraryDB.size(); i++) {
            if (libraryDB.get(i).compareTo(libraryUI.get(i)) != 0) {
                theSame = Boolean.FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(theSame) {
        System.out.println("The same");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not the same");
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't have access to change Entity

Comment: @Amir251251, did you come right? If so please mark this question as resolved by checking the tick. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check if each of the two lists contains all the elements of the other list **and** their size is equal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Person person1 = new Person();
    Person person2 = new Person();
    Person person3 = new Person();
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Person> inputPersonList = new ArrayList<>();

    person1.Id(1);
    person1.setName("A");
    person1.setFamily("B");

    person2.Id(2);
    person2.setName("C");
    person2.setFamily("D");

    person3.Id(3);
    person3.setName("E");
    person3.setFamily("F");

    personList.add(person1);
    personList.add(person2);
    personList.add(person3);

    inputPersonList.add(person1);
    inputPersonList.add(person3);
    inputPersonList.add(person2);

    // compare the lists using the built-in "equals()" method, which considers order of elements
    System.out.println(personList.equals(inputPersonList) ?
            "equal (considering order)" : "not equal (considering order)");
    // then compare them with the other possibility
    System.out.println(areEqual(personList, inputPersonList) ?
            "equal (without considering order)" : "not equal (without considering order)");

}

public static boolean areEqual(List<Person> persons, List<Person> personsToo) {
    if (persons.containsAll(personsToo) && personsToo.containsAll(persons)
            && persons.size() == personsToo.size()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this does not consider the case of duplicate elements correctly, because it only checks if an element is present in both lists, not if their count in the lists is equal. You could add `person1` a second time to `personList` and `person3` a second time to `imputPersonList` and the result would still be `true` respectively equality.

Answer (score 0):

As says Ambro-r you need use the Comparable interface but if you don't have access to the Entity, you should extends Book Class.

```
public class MyBook extends Book implements Comparable {

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    //compare with other book with the attributes what you want maybe could:
    return this.isbn > ((MyBook) o).isbn
}

@Override
public  String toString() {
   //return super.toString() or your own toString 
}
```

Then you should create lists of MyBook objects.